# Identifying multiple arduino boards on Raspberry Pi

Tags: arduino

I have a project where I need to connect multiple arduino boards on my RPi. I succeeded to do that with USB connection. My problem is that I have to determine the serial ports to which the boards are connected, dynamically.

I googled that and I found stuff like lsusb. This command returns id's of devices but i need something like `/dev/ttyACM0` ...

I identified the arduino boards with `ls /dev/serial/by-id/`, but also with this, I do not get the result that I needed(the name of the port). Is there some command that I can use to give me a result set (arduino id, `/dev/tty...`). Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to lookup udev rules
I am away from my machine at the moment, but what you do is to use lsusb to determine the serial number of the arduino
Then in udev rules file you setup a symbolic link that gets created everytime that arduino gest plugged in
So instead of trying to figure out what /dev/ttyACM? is attached to what arduino.  You end up with a symlink like /dev/ttyArduino001 that always points to the same arduino board.  Even after a reboot
If you need more info say so and I will lookup my udev rules